# Resize child video element according to parent div in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I can successfully drag and drop the div and its containing video element. But on resizing the div, the video element is not getting resized.

**CSS:**

```
.drsElement {
 position: absolute;
 border:8px solid #a00000;
}

.drsMoveHandle {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #CCC;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
 cursor: move;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="myDiv" class="drsElement drsMoveHandle"
     style="left: 400px; top: 280px; width: 50px; height: 100px;
     background: #348534; text-align: center">
    <video id="localVideoPlayer" autoplay muted  ></video>
</div>
```

How to resolve the issue ? I am using [this](http://www.twinhelix.com/javascript/dragresize/demo/) example.

Comment: Have you tried any CSS? `video {width: 100%;}` etc?

Comment: I tried, but still the same result- it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying numerous ways I have discovered that no method can resize the video element if it has already started playing media. It throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error on trying to set width or height. So, I have decided to use canvas and setting the video element as the source to the `drawImage` method of the canvas context serves my purpose. Now my markup is as follows:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="drsElement drsMoveHandle"
     style="left: 20px; top: 20px; 
     background: #348534; text-align: center">
    <canvas id="localVideoCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.drsElement {
 position: absolute;
 border:8px solid #a00000;
}

.drsMoveHandle {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #CCC;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
 cursor: move;
}

#localVideoCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'r trying to re-size your div use

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

OR

If you'r trying to re-size your video according to div use

```
video{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about this